# Best way to monitor updates to a single mongo record from express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an audit collection with a single row like this in mongo.

```
{ total: 100, successes: 95, failures: 5}
```

I would like to stream this to a UI using [socket.io](http://socket.io/). I am able to do it with a mongo collection like this.

```
const Audit = require('../models/audit'); // Mongoose Model

module.exports = function(app){

    const http = require('http').Server(app);
    const io = require('socket.io')(http);

    Audit.find().tailable().cursor()
        .on('data', function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
            io.emit('audit', doc); // push to subscribed clients
        });
};
```

However this only seems to support inserts.  How do I do this when I want to monitor changes to a single row?

Comment: you want to  check if any document is updated in the collection

Comment: "match check"?  Is this a feature of mongo? Unclear what you mean.

Comment: Updated my comment. what I really mean is than the moment any row(document in mongodb) is updated you should know

Comment: Well I tried updating a record in mongo but the `.on('data'` function is never fired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a cursor using the `awaitData` and `tailable` flag? See MongoDBs Node.JS driver [API Reference](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#addCursorFlag).